# ssmtp Cannot open mail.server.com:25

Tags: 12.04, email, ssmtp

I am trying to configure ssmtp on our Ubuntu 12.04 server. However I had no luck so far. My ssmtp.conf looks like this:

```
root=me@server.com
mailhub=mail.server.com:25
rewriteDomain=
hostname=hostname.server.com
AuthUser=me
AuthPass=mypassword
UseTLS=YES
FromLineOverride=YES
```

When I try to send mails I get `ssmtp: Cannot open mailhub:25`. When I use sudo the error message reads a little different `ssmtp: Cannot open mail.server.com:25`
The server should normally accept SMTP on port 25 and I can contact it with telnet `mail.server.com 25`. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you trying to send mail?

Comment: `ssmtp guy@server.com < mail.txt` and `ssmtp guy@server.com`

Comment: Maybe try `mailx guy@server.com < mail.txt`. Also, anything interesting in `/var/log/mail.log`?

Comment: Mailx is not installed. Without sudo: `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf not found`, `Unable to locate mailhub`, with sudo: `SSL connection using (null)`

Comment: At least in case with my mailhub I had to use port 587 because 25 was constantly blocked.  Try this one out,  also see if you mail server can be accessed from another port. Also , last resort could be to switch to msmtp. That's what I have now

Comment: You said mailx isn't installed.  I'm not 100% sure , but you'd need mailutils installed to do anything with mail. Do that

Comment: Thanks! Same issue on 25 and 587. telnet working for both. other ports are blocked. mailutils did not help :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok I figured it out... I had to use `UseSTARTTLS=YES` instead of `UseTLS=YES`. Also I had to enter `root:me@server.com:mail.server.com:25`in /etc/ssmtp/revaliases. Hope this helps others as well.

If you want to use other user accounts than root, you will have to add those to /etc/ssmtp/revaliases as well and add them to the 'mail' group.

Comment: the part about /etc/ssmtp/revaliases was quite useful. In my case (not using gmail) I had to use UseTLS=YES *instead* of UseSTARTTLS=YES and not the other way around. Looking into /var/log/mail.log helped me find that out. (Ubuntu 20.04, inmotionhosting.com mail server)

Answer (score 8):

There is another case, which I encountered, where this happens: If you remove read access to `ssmtp.conf` from `others` because you don't want the password to be visible to all users, then you will get the same error unless your account has read access to that file. For example, when trying `sendmail` you might have to do `sudo sendmail` instead.

Comment: This solved this for me. Seems like a different method could be to change the group of the ssmtp.conf file to "mail" or something, then add your user there, and `chmod g+r` that file.

Comment: For a secure way to grant appropriate permissions, see here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP#Security